# Pass Data To Objective-C View Controller From Swift View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I am trying to pass data from a Swift View Controller (viewControllerA) to a Objective-C View Controller (viewControllerB) with the following code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "ViewControllerB") {

        var navController : UINavigationController! = UINavigationController()

        navController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController

        let viewControllerB : ViewControllerB! = ViewControllerB()

        viewControllerB.navigationController?.topViewController

        // Not sure how to alloc init code in an Objective-C Class in Swift file

        viewControllerB.dictionaryB = [NSObject : AnyObject]()
        viewControllerB.arrayB = [AnyObject]()

        viewControllerB.dictionaryB = self.dictionaryA
        viewControllerB.arrayB = self.arrayB

    }
}
```

My properties (dictionaryB & arrayB) are coming up null after prepareForSegue is called. How can I fix this?

Comment: Where are `dictionaryA` and `arrayB` declared? Initialized? What are the previous two lines for if you’re immediately overwriting the values they set?

Comment: @PaulCantrell They are declared as properties in viewControllerB

Answer (score 0):

You grab the destination VC, `navController`, but then do nothing with it.

The code then creates a `ViewControllerB`, assigns dicts & arrays to it, but then does nothing with `viewControllerB`, so it will simply be deallocated at the end of this method (from what I can tell from the posted code).

There's also a line `viewControllerB.navigationController?.topViewController` which appears to do nothing.

I'm guessing you hoped to do something like:

```
viewControllerB.navigationController?.topViewController = viewControllerB
```

But that won't compile; you actually need:

```
navController.viewControllers = [viewControllerB].
```